# Is it possible to generate non-blocking calls with dbusxx-xml2cpp?

Tags: c++, code-generation, dbus

I would like to generate C++ headers using `dbusxx-xml2cpp` where some methods are non-blocking, e.g. using `invoke_method_noreply` instead of `invoke_method`. Is this possible?

For example the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<node name="/me/MyService">
    <interface name="me.MyService">
            <method name="MyMethod">
                    <arg direction="in" type="s" name="argument"/>
            </method>
    </interface>
</node>
```

Would generate (partly):

```
void MyMethod(const std::string& argument)
{
    ::DBus::CallMessage call;
    ::DBus::MessageIter wi = call.writer();

    wi << argument;
    call.member("MyMethod");
    ::DBus::Message ret = invoke_method (call);
}
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
void MyMethod(const std::string& argument)
{
    ::DBus::CallMessage call;
    ::DBus::MessageIter wi = call.writer();

    wi << argument;
    call.member("MyMethod");
    bool ret = invoke_method_noreply (call);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the annotation org.freedesktop.DBus.Method.NoReply"

Example XML:

```
<node>
  <interface name="org.test.example">
    <method name="NoReplyMethod">
      <arg name="data" direction="in" type="i"/>
      <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Method.NoReply" value="true"/>
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

Generated Code:

```
void NoReplyMethod(const int32_t& data)
{
    ::DBus::CallMessage call;
    ::DBus::MessageIter wi = call.writer();

    wi << data;
    call.member("NoReplyMethod");
    assert (invoke_method_noreply (call));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any documentation about this that you know of?

Comment: This linkhas some information http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/dbus-cplusplus/index.php?title=Introspection_Format